# Would like to understand why the SOME function in examples below are returning inconsistent results

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm new to common lisp, and I am using SBCL (version 2.1.5) in linux,
I am learning about the SOME applicative operator, and I ran these 2
examples that seem to me to be giving inconsistent results:

- (some #'= '(1 2 3 4 5) '(5 4 3 2 1))
  T
- (some #'= '(1 2 3 4) '(4 3 2 1))
  NIL

The first invocation makes sense to me, but the second invocation
seems to be inconsistent. Why wouldn't the second invocation also
return 'T' like the first invocation?

Thanks for any help understanding this.

Comment: The second one is comparing `(= 1 4)`, `(= 2 3)`, `(= 3 2)` and `(= 4 1)`. None of those are true, so it returns false. In the first one, `(= 3 3)` is true, so it returns true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```lisp
(some #'= '(1 2 3 4) '(4 3 2 1))
```

means

```lisp
(or (= 1 4)
    (= 2 3)
    (= 3 2)
    (= 4 1))
```

That is: the function `=` is applied to the first elements of the given sequences, then to the second elements and so on.  It finishes as soon as one of the sequences is exhausted.

If you want to have the set intersection between two lists (the `:test` is a bit redundant here, because the default test `eql` also compares numbers):

```lisp
(intersection '(1 2 3 4) '(4 3 2 1) :test #'=)
```

This returns the entire intersection.  If you only need to test whether there is any common member, finishing as soon as one is found, you could do it like this:

```lisp
(find-if (lambda (e)
           (member e '(4 3 2 1)))
         '(1 2 3 4))
```

or

```lisp
(loop :for e :in '(1 2 3 4)
      :thereis (member e '(4 3 2 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at a simpler [`SOME`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm) example:

```
(SOME #'EVENP '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

It is simpler because there is only one sequence of values being iterated.
As a consequence, the predicate is expected to be given a single argument. The result here is T because some elements in the input lists satisfy `EVENP`.

When you have more than one sequence, they are iterated in parallel: the first elements of each sequence are used together as arguments to  the predicate.
Then all the second elements are used as arguments to the second call to the predicate, etc. until at least one sequence is empty.

For example, let's define a function `divisible-by` that takes two arguments:

```
USER> (defun divisible-by (value divisor)
        (= 0 (mod value divisor)))
DIVISIBLE-BY
```

You could say, for example `(DIVISIBLE-BY 10 5)` and it would return T.

Let's also [`TRACE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm) it (the actual trace output is implementation dependent, here I'm using SBCL).

```
USER> (trace divisible-by)
(DIVISIBLE-BY)
```

Let's use it in a call to `SOME`, with 2 lists (any other amount of sequences is an error):

```
USER> (some #'divisible-by '(10 20 30) '(3 7 6))
  0: (DIVISIBLE-BY 10 3)
  0: DIVISIBLE-BY returned NIL
  0: (DIVISIBLE-BY 20 7)
  0: DIVISIBLE-BY returned NIL
  0: (DIVISIBLE-BY 30 6)
  0: DIVISIBLE-BY returned T
T
```

You can see that each pair of elements from both lists are used as arguments to the successive calls to `divisible-by`.

The same logic applies to other higher-order functions in Common Lisp:

```
USER> (mapcar #'list '(0 1 2) '(a b c) '(x y z))
((0 A X) (1 B Y) (2 C Z))
```